# Array of struct pointers - overrides struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm learning C and encountered a problem with structs.

Let's assume I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
} Structure;

int main (void) {
  Structure *structs[2];
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Structure s = {i};
    structs[i] = &s;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", structs[i]->x);
  }

  return 1;
}
```

The output is:

```
1
1
```

I don't understand why the new struct is overring the old one.

It might be a stupid problem. But I don't get it.

Thanks!

Solved:

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
} Structure;

int main (void) {
  Structure *structs[2];
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Structure *s = (Structure *)malloc(sizeof(Structure));
    s->x = i;
    structs[i] = s;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", structs[i]->x);
    free(structs[i]);
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object `s` doesn't live beyond the scope of the first `for` loop. Storing its address is pointless, and dereferencing it is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Thanks! I got it! I changed my code to using the heap as storage.

Answer (score 3):

Code has undefined behavior. You are holding the reference of a local automatic variable.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Structure s = {i};
    structs[i] = &s;

} // life time of s ends here
```

All bets are off since code has UB. So, it doesn't matter what output you get.

Comment: It's not that the variable is local - if it was `static`, no UB would be here. The correct (complete) terminology is *"local automatic"* variable.

Comment: @H2CO3: Actually, it's *"object with block scope and automatic storage duration"*. I don't believe the standard uses the term "local" for this -- or "variable" for that matter.

Comment: @KeithThompson Right, rather "block scope" - but I didn't imply "variable" was part of the terminology either (that's why it's ouside the quotation marks and the italics).

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for correcting me to use the correct terminology.

Comment: @Mahesh Thank Keith Thompson for that - it turned out that I wasn't entirely correct either :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Structs s = {i};` only has scope within the for loop where you declared it. Once you leave that loop, it no longer exists, even though you still have a pointer to it. It's all undefined behavior after that.